# Generate Ant buildfiles error

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

Im trying to generate ant buildfiles.But Im receiving a error

```
"The build class path order of the source directories of project library is not correct. Exported Ant buildfile will not compile your sources correctly until you swap the order of these directories:
gen<->src"
```

Im building from eclipse using file->export->Ant-buildfile

When im trying to build from command-line i recieve:

```
$ ant debug
Buildfile: /build.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "debug" does not exist in the project "com.Grupp01.gymapp.MainActivity".
```

Screen capture of error and eclipse:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you run latest version of adt and have updated android manager tools to latest versions?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same probem. Solving was: right click on library ->Properties ->Java Build Path -> Order and Export. Entry "gen" must be upper then "src" (use buttons up, down).

Answer (score 0):

I have dolved this using this steps.

Right Click on your project -> Properties -> Java Build Path-> "gen" should be upper than "src". So, re arrage the folders. It worked for me.